# Spring & AspectJ logger

Tags: java, spring, logging, annotations, aspectj

I'm trying to create a little spring project with annotations logging.

First of all I added Spring `AOP xsd` and `namespace`:

```
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
```

and added the `AOP aspectj proxy`

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" expose-proxy="true" />
```

Added the annotation interface:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Loggable {
   String message() default " -- ";
}
```

After that I created the Aspect class:

```
@Aspect
public class LogManager {

    @Before("execution(* spring.TestServlet.processRequest(..))")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

        System.out.println("logBefore() is running!");
        System.out.println("hijacked : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        System.out.println("******");
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
    public void publicMethod() {
        System.out.println("Pointcut success");
    }

    @Around("publicMethod() && @annotation(spring.aspects.annotations.Loggable)")
    public void logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Log logger = getLog(joinPoint.getTarget().getClass());
        StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
        Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
        String className = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getName();
        String methodName = className + ": " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
        String argString = "";

        logger.error(methodName + " Started");
        logger.error("Params: ");

        for (Object arg : args) {
            logger.error("    " + arg.getClass().getName() + ": " + arg);
        }

        sw.start();
        joinPoint.proceed();
        sw.stop();

        System.out.println(methodName + "finished execution in " + sw.prettyPrint());
        logger.error(methodName + " finished execution in " + sw.prettyPrint());
    }
}
```

After this setup I added the annotation to my methods but nothing happened.

I'm running this code on `Tomcat Server 8.0.1 JDK 1.7 Java EE 7 Web`.
Thanks in advance for every help,
Mattia

Comment: I didn't see any evidence you've [configured aspectj on your build tools](http://gerrydevstory.com/2014/06/28/spring-declarative-transaction-management-with-jdk-proxy-vs-aspectj/) (maven).

Comment: I'm not using maven or gradle, I downloaded jars and included them in my project.
I'm using this little example in order to learn and import all of this in a bigger project built without maven or gradle.

Comment: Then I don't think aspectj will work magically for you.. you need to dig the documentation and find out how to use it manually

Comment: Thanks, I completely ignored the configuration part, focusing only on downloading jars.
Solved by adding bin folder to windows PATH

Thanks again.